# Should I use thread-seal tape for steam pipe?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, steam

I am getting ready to replace the [pressuretrol](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/can-i-trust-my-pressuretrol) of my oil-burning steam boiler, which provides heat and hot water.  Should I use [thread-seal tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_seal_tape) (aka. Teflon tape, PTFE tape, tape dope, or plumber's tape) when attaching the new pressuretrol?  If so, should I use the same kind of tape that I use for water pipes, or is there a special kind for use with steam pipes?

(The [pressuretrol datasheet](http://customer.honeywell.com/techlit/pdf/PackedLit/60-2341.pdf) describes the connector as “1/4 inch female pipe thread.”  I presume that is a synonym for [national pipe thread taperered thread (NPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread), so the threads themselves are providing the seal, and there is no gasket.)

Comment: Nit-picky wording detail: with NPT threads, the threads *don't* provide a seal, thus the need for thread sealing tape or compound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite pipe thread sealer is RectorSeal #5. [Here's a link](http://www.rectorseal.com/index.php?site_id=1&product_id=212). I see according to its datasheet that its rated for steam pipes. You might have to let it dry a little while before pressuring, but after that its good for 2600 psi.

Comment: It should be good for my measly 2 psi then.

Comment: Why do you like it so much?

Comment: My brother recommended it for use on gas pipes, and I just found it works well, stays soft enough to take apart and doesn't leak.